Is it possible to regain my cat's trust or have I permanently damaged our relationship?
We took in a stray cat who had been abandoned and living on the street. Hungry, skin and bones, lonely, not chipped, not neutered.  Not feral, was comfortable around us.  I got him vaxxed, neutered, and chipped and all was well.  He is a Siamese mix and they tend to pick a "favorite" person and I clearly was his, probably because I was the one who brought him inside.  For a month, he was so sweet, seeking me out for pets and scritches, head butting me, rubbing against my legs, flopping on the floor in front of me to show he felt safe.  He loved me and I love him.
Today I was having a bad day.  I WFH and woke up to see my inbox exploding with fires to put out.  Shortly thereafter the cat was cuddling and purring with me and I noticed the cat's breakaway collar was missing so I went to look around the house for it.  I found it in our bedroom, next to the a/c heating vent... where he had randomly decided to pull the cover off of.  This is not the first time he's done this and it's very frustrating.  He had also knocked over his water bowl in the kitchen, which he also loves to do, and I slipped on the water and fell.  My phone was blowing up with texts from my manager and I was trying to fix the vent and then get the collar back on the cat and he kept wriggling away and growling and hid under a chair.  He also scratched me.
I am not proud of this but I pulled him out by the scruff of his neck, put the collar back on, and yelled at him for making my miserable morning worse.  I put him in the guest room, which was his safe room when we were introducing him to our resident dog and cat and shut him in there.  There is plenty of food and water in there for him and a litter box.
After I calmed down I went to check on him.  He was hiding under the bed.  I tried to coax him out and he wouldn't budge.  I got him out by giving treats but went I tried to pet him and apologized he would shy away from me and hide deeper under the bed.  I left the safe room door open.  A few hours later he came out and I gently tried to make amends by getting on the floor with him and offering my hand as a peace gesture.  He didn't accept the gesture and ran to hide under the couch.  I peeked under here to see him and gave more treats.  He took them but then scooted back further under the couch.  I tried another friendly hand and he hissed at me.
Every since then he's been avoiding me like he is scared of me.  He is roaming put and about the house but runs away if I come near him.  He did play with me with the feather on a stick toy and accepted a night time treat but otherwise is still skittish around me and not wanting me to come near him.
I am heartbroken and so ashamed of myself. I have NEVER behaved like this with any cat I have owned.  He was cuddling with me one moment and then I yelled at him and scared him.  I went from being someone he felt safe around to someone to fear.  He had only till then known me as the kind and gentle woman who brought him in from the outside and gave him a home and so much love and I suddenly turned into an angry person who yells at him.
I am giving him lots of space now, but I'm afraid that I have completely broken his trust today and our relationship will never be the same. I keep reading articles online about how when cats are punished they never look at their owners the same way again.  I am a very lonely person with not many friends and a stressful job and he made my life better and I ruined it and lost my new little kitty friend.
How badly have I damaged things?  Do you think he forgive me or is this a bridge too far?  What can I do to regain his trust? Or do I need to just accept he will never trust my again?
I am so ashamed and upset at myself and so sad.  He was my little buddy and I scared him for no reason except my own stress.  I took my work stress out on him and I feel so horrible.  Please tell me if this relationship is salvageable or if I need to just give up and live with a cat who doesn't feel safe around me anymore.

Yes, of course you can regain her trust. It might take a while, you just need to be patient.
But you also need to work on your behavior - if you have a stressful lifestyle, then try to some activities to release that stress - like some physical exercise, or yoga, or something else.
